# Powershell webbrowser refresh makes my content disappear

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I am writing a small powershell script using windows forms which generates an HTML signature.

The user can edit size, color etc and the script generates the html as a from their choices, and updates (theoretically) my WebBrowser preview when they press a preview button.

My WebBrowser Control:

```
$Preview = new-object System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser
$Preview.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(500,30)
$Preview.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(260,226)
$Preview.ScrollBarsEnabled = $false
$Form.Controls.Add($Preview)
```

Update code:

```
$Preview.DocumentText = $html 
$Preview.Update()
$Preview.Refresh()
```

This works the first time you run it, i.e. it goes from a blank preview window and updates with the html.

However, every subsequent time the button is pressed it just clears the window?

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all I had to do was remove the `$Preview.Update()` and `$Preview.Refresh()` lines.

Aaaaarghh!